# What is `react-text`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is `react-text` ?

It does not exist in the code, but it appears in html after rendering

[image]

Comment: Can't remove this comment and text `" "` ?

Comment: No, you can't. React needs it.

Comment: @ivarni ok. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React tries to diff the minimal amount of dom it can and it needs to track the dom rendered for every child. For empty string childs it tracks it using these comment tag. So no, you cannot (and should not) remove these.

## More

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html#no-more-extra-ltspangts

> We received some amazing contributions from the community in this release, and we would like to highlight this pull request by Michael Wiencek in particular. Thanks to Michael’s work, React 15 no longer emits extra  nodes around the text, making the DOM output much cleaner. This was a longstanding annoyance for React users so it’s exciting to accept this as an outside contribution.

## More More

These will not appear if you do not render anything e.g. `null`. But for a string like  (a space), these will appear.

Comment: Any specific reason why you decided to basically post the same answer that's already posted on the suggested duplicate?

Comment: @ivarni my answer was posted and accepted before a duplicate was identified

Comment: No, You posted the answer 10 minutes after I cast the second close-vote. https://imgur.com/a/7zFqUbF

Comment: Rob, who cast the first close vote also edited it a good 45 minutes before your answer was posted, so there would have been closevotes on it for way more than 10 minutes.